# Can't programmatically change <input>'s value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a few [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com/) strategies on my spare time, and most of these strategies can be configured via the *Inputs* tab in the *Configurations* window.

For some reason I'd like to be able to change these inputs' values programmatically via JavaScript. I've managed to make it work for checkboxes using `input.click()`, but I haven't yet found a way to change the value of a `text` input so that the change is picked up by TradingView.

For example if you select a `text` input via the browser's inspection tool

[image: My TradingView strategy's Configuration window]

and then type in the console

```js
$0.value = 50
```

you'll notice that the input is **visually** updated and now shows `50` but the strategy's chart and the Strategy Tester's data are not. Also, if you hover the input with your mouse you'll see its value be reset to the original value (`8`). Which means the change wasn't picked up by TradingView.

Does anyone knows how to work around this?

Comment: This question doesn't really seem like programming so much as trying to hack around a web app's programming. Most likely, the terms of service of this application forbid the use of programmatic access to their site. Be forewarned.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the page is listening to events on the input and updating things when they fire. By directly setting the value you are not firing any of the events.

There are potentially three events I can think of off hand that it might be listening to, depending on the developer.

Try the following to see if any of them work

```
$0.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
$0.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'));
$0.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried dispatching events manually after setting the value and it doesn't work :(

Comment: If the screen is updating based on keyboard inputs into an input element then it has to be responding to one of these events.  You should verify you are actually firing the events on an Input element and not a containing element like a div.

Comment: I know it's crazy but I've tried dozen of times and it doesn't work. I've even tried dispatching an `input` event, instanciating a `KeyboardEvent` directly, using `bubbles: true` ... nothing works. jQuery methods don't work either. And yeah I'm sure the `<input>` element was selected and not another one. That's why I posted this question, because I've never encountered this problem.

Comment: The only thing I can think is that you aren't selecting the correct element but it's hard to figure out exactly what is going on without seeing the page myself. You could try poking through the javascript on the page to see what it does.